# What's the difference between 'user', 'currentUser', and 'account'?

Tags: users, user-profile, current-user

I notice in the template examples that `user`, `account` and `currentUser` are all being used, but not seeing clear documentation on these. Can someone perhaps explain the difference?

Example [User Registration Form](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form) uses `{{ account.username }}`

Example [User Profile Form](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/user-profile-form) uses `{{ user.username }}`

and there is a [Global Variable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/global-variables) called `{{ currentUser.username }}`

I assume that `user` is perhaps just an alias to `currentUser` (unless explicitly defined otherwise)? And that `account` is something that is used exclusively for `user/saveUser`?

The reason I ask is that I'm creating edit profile pages, and want to make sure they are secure. Seems like just using `user` is enough, as that appears to always be populated correctly with the `currentUser` data; and if not logged-in it redirects to the log-in page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:**

As of Craft 3.x, the deprecated `user` variable no longer works. Make sure to use the proper `currentUser` variable instead!

---

**Original:**

`user` and `currentUser` are exactly the same. They contain the UserModel of the **currently logged in user**.

Why are they exactly the same? Originally, `user` was the preset value for the current user. However, there were many cases of people *manually* setting a value for `user` (often in the context of a `for` loop through a group of users), and therefore overwriting the preset value. So P&T introduced `currentUser` as an alias which was much less likely to be overwritten.

`account` will only exist on the [User Registration Form](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form). Its value is automatically set when the form is submitted. `account` represents the values entered during the attempted registration (whether the registration was successful or not).

For the sake of your Edit Profile pages, you'll want to use `currentUser`.

Comment: We used to only set `user` to the currently logged-in user, but after receiving some feedback that it wasn’t descriptive enough we decided to also add `currentUser` in [Craft 1.2](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2333). We’ve tried to update all of the documentation to reference `currentUser` instead of `user` but the User Profile Form was apparently overlooked. I just went in and updated it.